# How do I save a replay in Super Meat Boy on OS X?

Tags: macos, super-meat-boy

I've been playing Super Meat Boy on OS X, from Steam. I'd like to save a copy of some of my replays, but I can't find the keyboard shortcut. It's displayed at such a low resolution that it's impossible to read:

[image]

I've tried mashing keys at random, but haven't had any luck. What's the keyboard shortcut?

---

*edit:* Pressing [image: the shift key] causes this guy to appear in the corner for a second:

[image]

I'm not sure what this means but my list of replays remained empty so it seems like something else.

Comment: Did a cursory search of the Steam forums for SMB, don't see any complaints. Strange :/. I see references to it working, but with old post dates, invariably all Windows users.

Comment: Just downloaded the Mac version from the Humble Indie Bundle (not steam) and I see the same behavior. It also can't seem to connect to the internet, and gives a SQL Error all the time. Pretty sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the save icon respond after simply pushing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: It's actually just Shift, by itself, Shads0 had it right. However, you're right that nothing actually happens. My replay list is completely empty. I'm quite sad about this fact.

Comment: This now works for me on OS X. It was apparently fixed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

For PC, the default is Shift, so I would assume the Mac would be similar as there is no reason for it to have special controls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me. It causes an icon to pop up (see edited post), but my list of replays remains empty.

Comment: Anyway you can run in windowed mode and use the mac's zoom feature?

Comment: I couldn't find full-screen mode, so I've actually been playing in zoomed-in windowed mode already. Sadly, it doesn't improve things. :(

Comment: @JeremyBanks: if you run the game through steam you can get it fullscreen by adding "-fullscreen" to the launch option, but this however, doesn't change the resolution.